# laravel why i cant use releationshiop for data get with join

Tags: arrays, database, laravel, model-view-controller, eloquent

here is my controller:

```
 $homeTeamFacts = DB::table('match_facts')
            ->where('match_id', $match->id)
            ->join('players', 'match_facts.player_id', '=', 'players.id')
            ->where('players.team_id', '=', $homeTeamId)
            ->get();
```

and here is data collection i get:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1311 ▼
  #items: array:4 [▼
    0 => {#1325 ▼
      +"id": 2
      +"match_id": "1"
      +"player_id": "2"
      +"minutes": 90
      +"goals": null
      +"yellowCard": 1
      +"redCard": 0
      +"bench": 0
      +"created_at": "2021-01-08 11:12:59"
      +"updated_at": "2021-01-08 11:12:59"
      +"team_id": "1"
      +"position": "Gynėjas"
      +"photo": null
      +"name": "Tomas"
      +"surname": "Tomaitis"
      +"birth_date": null
      +"city": null
      +"height": null
      +"weight": null
    }
    1 => {#1332 ▶}
    2 => {#1323 ▶}
    3 => {#1333 ▶}
  ]
}
```

the problem is when i'm trying to get player name in view with "`{{$fact -> player-> name}}`"
when i get an error like this "Undefined property: stdClass::$player (View:..... "

But when i get data like this:

```
$MatchFacts = Match_fact::where('match_id', $match->id)
        ->get();
```

there are no problems and releationship works fine.
Is any options to make releationships work on my mentioned problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you are using a query builder for retrieve your data from DB `DB::table('match_facts')`

You can get player name using query builder, just add select `players.name` to your `select()` method

```
$homeTeamFacts = DB::table('match_facts')
    ->where('match_id', $match->id)
    ->join('players', 'match_facts.player_id', '=', 'players.id')
    ->where('players.team_id', '=', $homeTeamId)
    ->select('match_facts.*', 'players.name  as player_name')
    ->get();
```

and now you can access the player name using `$fact->player_name`

But in my opinion using Models and relations is the better option for your purposes

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are doing the query through the query builder directly instead of using Eloquent. That way, the results are not being hydrated as `Match_fact` instances but common stdClass ones. So, there's no `player` relationship defined on those.

To solve this, try to query your data using Eloquent and relationship instead

```
$MatchFacts = Match_fact::with('player')
        ->where('match_id', $match->id)
        ->get();
```

If you have defined the `player` relationship on `Match_fact` properly, then you should be able to do this:

```
@foreach($MatchFacts as $fact)
  {{ $fact->player->name }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: with this option is everything ok. Is any solution to get player name with this: $homeTeamFacts = DB::table('match_facts')
            ->where('match_id', $match->id)
            ->join('players', 'match_facts.player_id', '=', 'players.id')
            ->where('players.team_id', '=', $homeTeamId)
            ->get();

Comment: You could try adding ```->select('match_facts.*', 'players.name')```

Answer (score 0):

I think when you join more than one table means the result will be  not an actual instance of that model will be just a collection of data that's why the relationship does not work , you can get the name of player by add  select in which you will specify the columns do you can add even the name of the player as the column selected so in a collection of data will be a name of the player also as player_name

```
 $homeTeamFacts = DB::table('match_facts')->select([                DB::raw('players.name as player_name'),])

        ->where('match_id', $match->id)
        ->join('players', 'match_facts.player_id', '=', 'players.id')
        ->where('players.team_id', '=', $homeTeamId)
        ->get();
```

Comment: Maybe you can give an advice, how to get player name with joins? or maybe use different way to query data.